# How to write these complex MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

I have the following 2 tables :

table 'captain'

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | captain1 |
| 2 | captain2 |
| 3 | captain3 |
| 4 | captain4 |
| 5 | captain5 |
| 6 | captain6 |
| 7 | captain7 |
| 8 | captain8 |
| 9 | captain9 |
| 10 | captain10 |

table 'expedition'

| id | number | id_captain | id_navire | id_hero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 10 | 9 | 6 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 4 |
| 7 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 8 |
| 9 | 9 | 9 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | 10 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 11 | 11 | 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 12 | 12 | 8 | 6 | 1 |
| 13 | 13 | 5 | 8 | 6 |
| 14 | 14 | 4 | 9 | 9 |
| 15 | 15 | 3 | 10 | 4 |
| 16 | 16 | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 17 | 17 | 9 | 3 | 3 |
| 18 | 18 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 19 | 19 | 9 | 8 | 10 |
| 20 | 20 | 7 | 2 | 2 |

and I have this query:

The captain or captains who guided the most expeditions
itied this in SQL:

```
select id_captain, count(expedition.id) as expedition_count
  from expedition
  group by id_captain
  having expedition_count = max(expedition_count);
```

but no success. I am expecting the result to be like this :

| name | expedition_count |
| --- | --- |
| captain1 | 3 |
| captain9 | 3 |
| captain8 | 3 |

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: This: `having expedition_count = max(expedition_count)` cannot work. In the `HAVING` clause you look at one aggregated row at a time. For that row there is one `expedition_count`, so applying `MAX` on that value (`max(expedition_count)`) cannot do much. Depending on the DBMS you'll either get a syntax error or `max(expedition_count)` just resolves to `expedition_count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is several steps: Get the counts per caption, get the maximum count, only show the captains with maximum count.

A typical approach is to use a window function (available since MySQL 8):

```
select id_captain, expedition_count
from
(
  select 
    id_captain,
    count(*) as expedition_count,
    max(count(*)) over () as max(expedition_count)
  from expedition
  group by id_captain
) analyzed
where expedition_count = max_expedition_count;
```

Or a subquery:

```
select id_captain, count(*) as expedition_count
from expedition
group by id_captain
having expedition_count = 
(
  select count(*)
  from expedition
  group by id_captain
  order by count(*) desc
  limit 1
);
```

Comment: i have two other queries i will add them when i redit the question. i hope i get a help thanks in advance.

Comment: can anyone help me with the two others queries?

Comment: You should make this separate requests showing your attempts and explaining where you get stuck.

Comment: this is how far I can get with query q2 :

Comment: select name, min(nb_ville)  as nb_ville_crossed
from (select name, count(step.id) as nb_ville 
      from step left join expedition on step.ID_expedition=expedition.id 
                 left join participates on expedition.ID=participates.id 
                 left join heros on participates.id_heros=heros.id 
      group by heros.nom      
      order by nb_ville desc) as tbl;