# How to get the average number of cities crossed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, average

I am a beginner at databases. I need to write some SQL queries.

The tables are:

***Expedition**(id, number, id_captain, id_ship, id_heros)

**City**(id, name)

**Heros**(id, family_name, first_name)

**Step**(id, index, id_expedition, id_city)*

sample data :

'Table expedition'

| **id** | **number** | **id_captain** | **id_ship** | **id_hero** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 10 | 9 | 6 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 4 |
| 7 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 8 |
| 9 | 9 | 9 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | 10 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 11 | 11 | 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 12 | 12 | 8 | 6 | 1 |
| 13 | 13 | 5 | 8 | 6 |
| 14 | 14 | 4 | 9 | 9 |
| 15 | 15 | 3 | 10 | 4 |
| 16 | 16 | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 17 | 17 | 9 | 3 | 3 |
| 18 | 18 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 19 | 19 | 9 | 8 | 10 |
| 20 | 20 | 7 | 2 | 2 |

table 'heros'

| **id** | **family_name** | **first_name** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | familyname1 | firstname1 |
| 2 | familyname2 | firstname2 |
| 3 | familyname3 | firstname3 |
| 4 | familyname4 | firstname4 |
| 5 | familyname5 | firstname5 |
| 6 | familyname6 | firstname6 |
| 7 | familyname7 | firstname7 |
| 8 | familyname8 | firstname8 |
| 9 | familyname9 | firstname9 |
| 10 | familyname10 | firstname10 |

**query1:** The family (based on the family name) with the least travelling (the fewest cities different crossings).

i have done this for the first query:

```
select expedition.id, id_hero, heros.family_name as Famille_expedition, count(distinct id_city) as city_count
from expedition, step, heros 
where expedition.id=step.id and expedition.id_hero=heros.id
group by id_hero
having city_count = 
(select count(distinct id_city) as min_city_count
from expedition, step
where expedition.id=step.id
group by id_hero
order by min_city_count asc
limit 1);
```

**query2:** The average of cities crossed by an expedition

I have no idea how to answer the second one.

Comment: The table and column names in your query, your example data and your table definitions are not consistent. Please edit your question so that all parts fit together.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the queries and the tables were in french.

Comment: In your first query, have you manually verified that your results are correct?

Comment: That is unfortunately not the only problem. Please take more time to think about your problem. You will see that the example data you present is not helpful for your question. To say something about the average cities crossed by an expedition, the `heros` table is irrelevant. On the other hand, we need information on the `steps`. What is the semantic of the `index` column? (btw., `index` and `number` are reserved and should not be used as column names). What is your expected outcome?  Please have a look at [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: [How to write these complex MySQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166011/how-to-write-these-complex-mysql-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first ask yourself what information do you need to answer your question?

From your question, I'd say the average number of crossings is just the sum of all entries in the `steps` table, divided by the number of `expeditions`, since in each step, one city is visited and the average of all visits is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT (
       (SELECT COUNT(s.id_city)
          FROM step AS s) /
       (SELECT COUNT(e.id)
          FROM expedition AS e) ) AS total_average__cities
```

That being said, it depends on how exactly you define **number of cities** and **crossing**. Imagine the following example data for the table `step`:

| id | idx | id_expedition | id_city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 9 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 8 | 3 | 3 | 9 |
| 9 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| 10 | 5 | 3 | 8 |

The table lists the steps for three expeditions. Expedition 1 goes from one city via another to a third. Expedition 2 goes directly from one city to another. And expedition 3 goes through several cities and visits one city twice along the way and also returns to the city that it started in.

The average number of cities over all these steps is `(3 + 2 + 5 [cities in all steps]) / 3 [expeditions] = 3.3333`. That is the result of the above query.

Now, if you define **number of cities** as meaning *unique* cities *for each expedition*, expedition 3 only visits 3 cities instead of 5. Then your average calculates as `(3 + 2 + 3 [unique cities/expedition in all steps]) / 3 [expeditions] = 2.6666`. The according query needs to count the distinct cities within each expedition before building the average:

```
SELECT (
       (SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.id_city) AS cnt
                                FROM step AS s
                            GROUP BY s.id_expedition) t) /
       (SELECT COUNT(e.id)
          FROM expedition AS e) ) AS total_average__cities
```

Now, if you define **crossing** as only covering *cities along the way*, expedition 1 only crosses 1 city and expedition 2 crosses none at all.

Then your query also needs to look differently. You need to filter the all cities to exclude the first and the last for each expedition. The subquery could look like this:

```
SELECT s.* FROM step s
JOIN (   SELECT id_expedition, 
                MAX(idx) AS max_idx, 
                MIN(idx) AS min_idx
           FROM step s
       GROUP BY id_expedition) minmax
  ON s.id_expedition = minmax.id_expedition
 AND s.idx > minmax.min_idx
 AND s.idx < minmax.max_idx
```

So for the case that you want the number of cities crossed excluding start and stop, your average would be computed as `(1 + 0 + 3 [intermediate cities in all steps]) / 3 [expeditions] = 1.3333`. The according query would be

```
SELECT (
       (SELECT COUNT(s.id_city) 
          FROM step s
          JOIN (   SELECT id_expedition, 
                          MAX(idx) as max_idx, 
                          MIN(idx) as min_idx
                     FROM step s
                 GROUP BY id_expedition) minmax 
            ON s.id_expedition = minmax.id_expedition
           AND s.idx > minmax.min_idx
           AND s.idx < minmax.max_idx) /
       (SELECT COUNT(e.id)
          FROM expedition AS e) ) AS total_average__cities
```

Finally, in case you want to *both* exclude start and stop *and* only want to count unique cities, your average would be computed as `(1 + 0 + 2 [unique intermediate cities in all steps]) / 3 [expeditions] = 1`.  The following query combines the two approaches from above:

```
SELECT (
       (SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_city) AS cnt
                                FROM step s
                                JOIN (   SELECT id_expedition, 
                                                MAX(idx) AS max_idx, 
                                                MIN(idx) AS min_idx
                                           FROM step s
                                       GROUP BY id_expedition) minmax
                                  ON s.id_expedition = minmax.id_expedition
                                 AND s.idx > minmax.min_idx 
                                 AND s.idx < minmax.max_idx
                            GROUP BY s.id_expedition) t) /
       (SELECT COUNT(e.id)
          FROM expedition AS e) ) AS total_average_cities
```

You can test all these queries in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2627d0135275df691db16378ec12eed3).

Comment: This is far more effort than is merited by the OP's effort. Great work.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort, well explained and cover all posibilities.